# How to see values of singular lines of javascript in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In chrome if I add a breakpoint to a function(That I know is going to execute when the html page loads), as soon as control reaches near the function, chrome stops the execution of everything and I see at the right side of the function all the current values of its parameters .EG.

```
function test(param , param2) {  param = "test" , param2 = undefined

}
```

now suppose the line I'd like to debug is not a function and instead its just a line of JS that is going to be executed,  Like so:

```
this.wrapper.css('padding-' + this.pointer.position, this.pointer.dimensions[this.pointer.xy]);
```

suppose I want to see the value of

```
[this.pointer.xy];
```

How can this be achieved in chrome ?

Comment: IIRC: hover or select_the_text+hover; alternativly "watch variables"

Comment: Can't you just write it's value to the console?

Comment: @JSantos , I taught there was a smarter way to do it , console.log seems quite manual , I don't mind doing that though ! but when u have a really huge script , doing console.log , becomes quite a headache

Comment: Select this.pointer.xy completely and keep mouse on it for some milliseconds

Comment: @TenaliRaman considering you're debugging everything is kinda manual :) I prefer, writing everything to console instead of viewing it in real time since it allows me to come back to the data later, but each one has it's own preferences. Regards.